# How to create independent samples of equal size?

Tags: r, sample

Here is how I currently create two independent samples, DS and RS:

```
data$rnd<-runif(nrow(data),0,1)
fraction<-0.5
DS<-subset(data, rnd <= fraction) 
RS<-subset(data, rnd > fraction)
```

obviously, this will only give me two samples of roughly equal size. I guess my cross-validation analysis would be more efficient if I could get exactly equal splits (however my sample has unequal n). I thought about a natural number generator that picks each number between 1 and N exactly once but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sample`:

```
mask<-sample(nrow(data),nrow(data)/2);
DS<-data[mask,]
RS<-data[-mask,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simulate new data or sample from the data you have?

If the latter, do sample(data, size, replace=false)

if you do help(sample) you will get all the details.